# Eclipse Forward / Back "Tab" History key?

Tags: eclipse

In regards to Eclipse (using Luna)

Is there a mappable hot key for forward and back "Tab History".

There is one for tabs in general (forward and back in order as they appear in the list - but prompts a list to select from).
There is also a forward and back "history" (e.g. LINE history).

Basically the "history" hotkeys almost do what I want, but they take into account every line clicked: e.g. I open tab 1, then tab 2, click 3 lines in tab 2, then use the back history, it takes me through those three lines before it takes me to tab 1.

I want it to go straight to tab 1 (previous tab in history).

I can accept the answer "No".

I just wanted to make sure as eclipse has a lot of options that you can easily overlook settings (e.g. Perhaps its a different setting completely - like: change how "history" works setting.

**EDIT:**
The current "back history" and "forward history" are by default <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
I want to know if there is an equivilent that navigates though only the tab history (excluding the specific line history of the current tab).

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what exactly you mean? Views?

Comment: The Back and Forward commands do not behave the way you describe. I just tested (in Eclipse Mars) to make sure I wasn't imagining it, but they don't jump line-to-line in the same file.

Comment: I admit, its inconsistent (doesn't always do it - I think it's determined by saving or something else unknown to me) - but IT DOES do it (In Luna), you spend more than 10 mins developing across multiple files, then use the back history a few times, it does it. **I think based on the replies, the answer is a simple "No"**.